# cannot open file using avformat_open_input - returns "Cannot open! Invalid data found when processing input"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ffmpeg

I am just playing with ffmpeg on iOS 5. I started with something simple, like opening .mov file.

The code fragment:

```
AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
av_register_all();

NSString* fileName =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"mov"];
NSLog(@"File exists? %i", [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileName]);
NSLog(@"FIle name: %@", fileName);
char errbuf[256];

int ret = avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, [fileName UTF8String], NULL, NULL);
    if(ret != 0) {
        av_strerror(ret,errbuf,sizeof(errbuf));
        NSLog(@"Cannot open! %s", errbuf);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Opened!");
    }
```

The test.mov exists in my bundle and avformat_open_input is trying to open it - but the avformat_open_input always returns (when decoded error code to string):

```
Invalid data found when processing input.
```

(the error code when the file is missing is another text, I tried it).

I suppose that maybe ffmpg is not compiled with .mov support, but I am not able to open any movie file. I tried to look at ./configure options, but didn't find any hint.